# python programme showing compilation error

Tags: python, oop, compiler-errors

i am new to python please try to solve the problem

time[0],Q,t demand_month is defined
showing error in the following code
expected as indented block

```
for j in range(1,9):
time.insert(j,time[j-1]+t+(1.00*(Q-t*demand_month)/demand_month))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to [indent](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) the second line, to tell python it is part of the for loop block:

```
for j in range(1,9):
    time.insert(j,time[j-1]+t+(1.00*(Q-t*demand_month)/demand_month))
```